# Unordered map in C++ not functioning as intended

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, counting, unordered-map

The program I am trying to make takes an "n * n" square matrix grid of size "n * n" with values in the range [1,n²]. Each integer appears exactly once except a number 'a' which appears twice and a number 'b' which is missing.

The task is to find the repeating and missing numbers 'a' and 'b'.

It should return a vector of two elements, {a,b}.

i.e. for the matrix {[1,2],[2,3]}, it should return vector {2,4}.

In my program, I am almost certain it logically outputs 'a' and 'b'. However, it always outputs [a,0]. 'b' is always 0.

Element 'b' should never be in the map, and hence the find function should determine the value of 'b'.

```cpp
vector<int> findMissingAndRepeatedValues(vector<vector<int>>& grid) { 
 
    int size = grid.size(); 
    unordered_map<int,int> map; 
    for(int r = 0; r < size; r++) { 
        for(int c = 0; c < size; c++) { 
            map[grid[r][c]]++; 
        } 
    } 
    int a = 0; 
    int b = 0; 
    for(int i = 1; i < size*size + 1; i++) { 
        if(map[i] == 2) { 
            a = i; 
        } 
        else if(map.find(i) == map.end()) { 
            b = i; 
        } 
    } 
    return vector<int> {a,b}; 
}
```

The map is being added created correctly. I believe it's something to do with the second for-loop.

Comment: *I am almost certain...* -- *I believe it's something to do...* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `if(map[i] == 2)` will add a an element if it wasn't already there making the `else if` never true.

Comment: After the first `for` loop, see what `map.size()` is.  Then after the second `for` loop (right before the `return`), look at what `map.size()` is.  See a difference?

Comment: Here's an example with a map that starts empty. You might think that `else if` would get hit every time, but it isn't. https://godbolt.org/z/v86T9nMTx

Comment: Swap the if statements. You could then save the result of map.find(i) to check the count.

Comment: If your intent is to search in the map, do not use `[]`.  Use `find()` and make use of the return value, i.e. `auto iter = map.find(i);`.

Comment: You can reduce the complexity by deducing b by noting that it is the value by which the element sum is short of a+Σ(i=1...n², i²)

Comment: *"The map is being added created correctly."* -- This tells me that you can hardcode it in your [mre]. Skip the matrix (and much of the intro of this question) and simply define a map for some simple case, such as `unordered_map<int,int> map = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}};` (A 2x2 matrix appears to be the simplest test case.) Now you can focus on the problematic part -- finding the value between 1 and 4, inclusive, that is not a key in `map`.

Comment: I don’t know that I’d choose a map at all.

Comment: It’s simpler with a vector https://godbolt.org/z/bTbjesxKf